# Webform template for all webforms in content type

Tags: webforms, theming

I have content type with attached webforms. There is currently 8 nodes with webforms. Is there a way to create one webform template for all of this webforms? Because right now I'm using multiple templates, like this:
- webform-form-11.tpl.php
- webform-form-12.tpl.php
- webform-form-13.tpl.php

But I want this:
 - webform-form-contenttypename.tpl.php

Is this possible?